# With CocoaPods setting search path to allow for parent node_modules

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have a react-native project called react-native-my-proj.  I used CocoaPods to set it up.  The `Podfile` I created looks like:

```
pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :inhibit_warnings => true

pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    ...
]
```

My file structure looks like

```
react-native-my-proj/
  ios/
    Pods/...
    RNMyProj/
      RNMyProj.h
      RNMyProj.m
    RNMyProj.xcodeproj/...
    RNMyProj.xcworkspace/...
    Podfile
    Podfile.lock
  node_modules/...
  index.js
  package.json
```

When I open up `RNMyProj.xcworkspace` in XCode, building works fine.

Now I have a react-native app, `my-app` that relies on `react-native-my-proj`.

```
npm install ../react-native-my-proj
```

Since `react-native` is already included in `my-app`'s `node_modules` folder, it doesn't get installed into `react-native-my-proj/node_modules` and building breaks because of the specified path in my `Podfile`.

I assume there *must* be a way to tell the Podfile to search parent directories' `node_modules`.  Either that or CocoaPod files shouldn't be added to `react-native-my-proj`'s repository, and when I add a reference to `node_modules/react-native-my-proj/ios/RNMyProj.xcodeproj` in `my-app.xcodeproj`'s Libraries, and add `libRNMyProj.a` to its "Link Binary With Libraries" section, I need to do something to make it ignore CocoaPod somehow.

I noticed that react-native has a `React.podspec` file.  Is that what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than using CocoaPods to install the libraries, have you tried manually linking the libraries in Xcode?

Comment: I'm *very* new to XCode, and couldn't figure out how to get a project set up.  The only thing I could figure out was how to use CocoaPods since that seemed to be what all the guides did.  I would *love* a guide for setting up a project that doesn't use CocoaPods

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with this same issue.  

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

You'll be installing the same libraries that you specified in the podfile as the sub-libraries (like RCTText, RCTImage, etc).  They'll be found in `node_modules/react-native/Libraries`